# CSS selector specifity with SVG inside <object>

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors

I have the following code:

```
<body class="active">
    <object data="css/svg/circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
        <p> Your browser doesn't support SVG.</p>
    </object>
</body>
```

The SVG is simple like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="../style.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg id="circle" height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

The `active` class on `<body>` is toggled through javascript. Then I have the following CSS:

```
#circle {
    opacity: 1;
}
.active #circle {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The thing is, if I add the SVG with the `<object>` tag, the second selector, `active #circle`, doesn't work. If I put the SVG inline then it works. Note that I am including the CSS on the SVG file as well.
I would like to use the `<object>` because the real SVG isn't really so simple so my html would get messy. Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: _"Is there a way to achieve that?"_ - not via CSS. `object` creates a separate "document", pretty much the same as an iframe would. And you can not select "into" an iframe based on a class the body element of the parent page has either.

Comment: Have you tried using the `<use>` element? You would use it something like this: `<svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="path/to/svg-file.svg#circle"></use></svg>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few ways you might could use

Leave `object` empty and load it as an inline svg using ajax, on page load, ...

HTML

```
<object data="" data-svg="path-2-image.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    <p> Your browser doesn't support SVG.</p>
</object>
```

...or why not into a plain element, like a `div`

```
<div data-svg="path-2-image.svg">
</div>
```

Script (concept)

```
<script>
    // on load/dom ready
    var trg = document.querySelector('[data-svg]');
    var svgpath = trg.getAttribute('data-svg');
    call-your-SVGloader-function(obj,svg);
</script>
```

*Note: I also think you need to use `trg.innerHTML = ...` for the object as you do with the div*

---

Was also thinking of using an image, though haven't tried if this actually works

```
<img src="path-2-image.svg" alt="">
```